# Google Calendar API PHP skip the client side authentication and turn everything into a web application instead of command line one

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am creating a code that must add, update and delete event to google calendar I have the email address of the user to be added.

How to have auto client side authentication( confirm authentication by itself and get verification code)?

And

Turn to a web application instead of command line?

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

    define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
    define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/calendar-php-quickstart.json');
    define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', 'client_secret.json');
    define('SCOPES', implode(' ',array(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY)));

    if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
      throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
    }

    function getClient() {
      $client = new Google_Client();
      $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
      $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
      $client->setAuthConfigFile(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
      $client->setAccessType('offline');

      $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);

      if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
        $accessToken = file_get_contents($credentialsPath);
      } else {
        // Request authorization from the user.
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
        print 'Enter verification code: ';
        $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

        $accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);

        if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
          mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $accessToken);
        printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
      }
      $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
      if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->refreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $client->getAccessToken());
      }
      return $client;
    }
    function expandHomeDirectory($path) {
      $homeDirectory = getenv('HOME');
      if (empty($homeDirectory)) {
        $homeDirectory = getenv("HOMEDRIVE") . getenv("HOMEPATH");
      }
      return str_replace('~', realpath($homeDirectory), $path);
    }

    $client = getClient();
    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
```

Cant get the tutorial to implement this....

Answer (score 0):

You cant.  In order to access private user data (like a users calendar) your application must first be authenticated by said user.

Possible solution:  Have the user authentication it the first time (will require the HTTP webpage to be displayed).  You will be given a refresh token.   Save the refresh token.  Your automated script can then use the refresh token to gain a new access token and update the calendar when ever it likes (no web display needed).

Comment: Thanks you, Now I can work under command line how to use it as web application getting the error:This application must be run on the command line. I have the PHP version greater than 5.4

Comment: You will have to authenticate the user the first time via a webpage.  There is no way to work around that.  Once you have the refresh token everything else can be automated to run command line.

Comment: I need the full application to be run under Webpage and I am not going to use command line in no case. I am new to google client API have to try getting refresh token and refresh the token to get new access token from Webpage . Thanks you.